# Set of subsequent limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If  a sequence is bounded then set of all subsequential limit of the sequence is bounded.

**Is the converse true?**

Comment: UNM, I assume you no longer stand by the question details you gave from before, so I won't continue the edit-war.  However, question details, your thoughts, etc. can be very helpful to others trying to answer your question.  I therefore implore you to include them in your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true.

If the sequence itself is not bounded, then the sequence must have a subsequence that is unbounded which means that the set of subsequential limits of the sequence must contain $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and that's contradictory.

To show the existence of such a subsequence, go forward like this:

Suppose that $a_n$ is unbounded, therefore for any $M>0$ we have $|a_n| > M$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Set $M=1,2,\cdots$ then you find a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $|a_{n_k}|>n$ and this subsequence is unbounded.

Comment: yeah, the arguement is absolutely correct!

Comment: @math.n00b Generally yes, but it depends on what topological space you're working in.  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296002/accumulation-point-at-infinity).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you consider $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to be valid "subsequential limits" (which are more commonly called "accumulation points" of a sequence).  I.e., it depends on whether you work in the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ or the topological space $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$.

- If $\infty$ and $-\infty$ *are* considered valid accumulation points, then a sequence is bounded *if and only if* it contains the accumulation point $\infty$ or the accumulation point $-\infty$ (or both).
- If $\infty$ and $-\infty$ *are not* considered valid accumulation points, then consider the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$.  This sequence has no accumulation points, so the set of accumulation points is bounded, vacuously.  But this sequence is not bounded.